# scrollbar is getting hidden in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I am struggling to get back the scrollbar in my `rails 4` app. Earlier everything worked well, then i tried to add turbolinks gem. After that I deleted it and restarted the server. Since then when the page loads, scrollbar appears for a second and then disappears. After inspecting the element in the chrome, I found that when page loads, within the body tag, a `style="overflow-y:hidden;"` gets added. I have no idea from where it is coming. If  I put a `style="overflow-y:scroll;"`, then after the page loads, I observe that another `style="overflow-y:hidden"` is added in front of the `style` tag that I added, over-riding it.

```
<body style="overflow:scroll;",style="overflow-y:hidden;">
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your style tag add the important flag. `style="overflow-y:scroll !important;"` This should override other styling